# Serilog .write(logevent) using mssqlserver sink

Tags: c#, serilog

Am reading log data (created using serilog from other apps) from a message queue (using rabbitmq) & want to write these to sql server table using serilog mssqlserver sink in a windows service.

Am attempting to go about this using the .Write(LogEvent) method in the serilog api.

Am struggling on the following parameters to populate from the data in the queue:

- LogEventLevel level
- IEnumerable <LogEventProperty> properties

Does anyone have a nice example of how to use this method with above params?

Answer (score 1):

When you write the events to the message queue, use `CompactJsonFormatter` to create the JSON, from https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact.

Then, to read them back out as Serilog events, use `LogEventReader` from https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact-reader.